# Varying Speed of Brushless Motor Within The Same Cycle

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

Is it possible to vary the speed of rotation of brushless motor in its driver within the same cycle of rotation? I read that BLDC drivers use sinusoidal waves to drive the motor, would it be possible to change the shape of one sine peak thereby causing slowdown in one part of the cycle?

My goal is to be able to navigate a two rotor drone, if I could modify speed in one part of one rotor, that could cause a tilt.

The idea is based on this research,

https://www.modlabupenn.org/2014/10/23/underactuated-rotor/

They modify the tilt of the blade causing it to slow down in one part of the cycle. I was wondering if the same result could be achieved through the driver.

Comment: Hopefully you can understand elementary mechanics. Calculate how much plus or minus torque your rotating mass needs to get the wanted angular velocity change during the wanted speed change time interval. You can also calculate the needed acceleration or braking power in watts. Then there's a possibility to calculate the needed electric drive signal.  You can easily end to impossible voltages or currents.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to vary the motors rotational rate during a single cycle, both sensored and sensorless speed controllers keeps track of where the rotor is, and can vary the PWM ratios dozens to hundreds of times per phase, which then alters the effective phase angle your using to turn that rotor,

Usually this is done to remove the effect of slip angle, but it can also be used to brake the motor if needed, either with an external braking resistor, or using the motor as a brake, which should be kept to a low duty cycle to prevent overheating the motor (all that rotational inertia ends up mostly as heat in the motor)

You will also probably want to check your math on the rate at which you can alter the rotational speed. the motor can speed up or slow down effectively at the same rate (ignoring air drag on the propeller), as its a phase angle of 90 or -90 degrees,

The actual paper alters the lift of half of the rotor over portions of its rotation, however where you slow the motor will cause a gyroscopic reaction that only applies a force along the shaft of the motor, and not causing a roll or pitch like I suspect your hoping for,

Technically you can still perform yaw and pitch with 2 rotors, but not roll. and they are a bit muddy as pitch will cause yaw.

Comment: You mean perform roll and pitch with 2 rotors using the approach I mentioned? Or using some other (simpler) way?

Comment: 2 rotors means 2 spinning propellers, I presume with at least 2 blades each, and also falls on the assumption of not being coaxial (forgot to mention it), As a really ugly way you could use 2 coaxial single blade propellers, by adjusting the advance between the blades that would give you roll, pitch and technically yaw. but does mean the motor controller should probably be a single one for both, as the timing controls need to be well regulated.

Comment: This is very useful.. do you happen to have any links / references on this approach?

Comment: Sorry, it came to my head as I was wrapping around the concept, by controlling the spacing between the blades, the lift generating elements would be closer together on 1 side of the rotation, meaning the lift is acting on that side causing a rotation, the rate at which you can change that advance would be the tell for how well it would work.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to control the motor in the way described, but that will not be equivalent to the mechanical system described. The mechanical system appears to alter the pitch of just one of the two blades of the propellor for part of a blade revolution. Altering the speed of the propellor would alter the speed and thrust of both blades equally.

Comment: Let me ask you and @Reroute, what would be a good way to get yaw, pitch, roll using one or two (with contra spin) rotor blades? I want to keep it as simple as possible without having rotors themselves tilting. Is single rotor + fins a good way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> They modify the tilt of the blade causing it to slow down in one part of the cycle. I was wondering if the same result could be achieved through the driver.

I think you are misunderstanding the article. They do not modify the tilt of the blade to cause it to slow down in one part of the cycle. It is the other way around. They slow down in one part of the cycle to cause the tilt of the blade to be modified. I do not believe you can have such fine control during rotation without building a custom BLDC motor.

Or you need to be able to reflash the motor driver software to give an external MCU direct control and also add an absolute positioning sensor (such as a photo-interruptor indexer or encoder).

> if I could modify speed in one part of one rotor, that could cause a tilt.

It sounds like you want to vary the rotor speed WITHOUT using their hinged rotor hub. In which case, no, it will not produce a tilt. At least if you use any propeller with more than one blade because tilting requires asymmetry in the thrust and when you slow down a multi-blade propeller in one part of the rotation, blades on all sides slow down which preserves the symmetry of thrust so no tilt will occur.

If you looked at and understood their hinged rotor hub, it is designed down on the other side. THeir hinged rotor hub is designed so that when it lags, the blade on one sides increases in AOA while the other side decreases and that asymmetry causes a tilt.

The main problem with the mono-blade approach is the inertia though. It requires an actual tangible slowing down of the rotor to produce a change in lift whereas the hinged rotor hub just requires the blades to lag or lead

Comment: I see; so they are doing what I wanted to do in my question. And you are saying this is not possible wout custom motor.

Comment: BTW I misused "one part of one rotor", I meant to say slowing down in one part of cycle.

Comment: @NetSmoothMF I don't see how. I looked into this a while back too. You at least need access to the firmware to give an external MCU complete control and would need to add an external photo-interruptor in order to have some form of absolute position sensing for the BLDC driver.

Comment: @NetSmoothMF I know what you meant. It doesn't change what I said.

Comment: The two biggest hurdles are the custom BLDC driver (or at least one modified so you have practically complete control and have added an absolute positioning) and the hinged rotor. The hinged rotor, in particular, is a huge pain in the ass if you want to scale things up a bit since they used 3D printing which I really don't trust and hacked an existing propeller blade onto it. I had not considered using a mono-blade propeller until you expressed the desired (even though it wasn't quite correct)  to try it without the hinged rotor hub which made me think of the mono-blade approach.

Comment: The main problem with the mono-blade approach is the inertia though. It requires an actual tangible slowing down of the rotor to produce a change in lift whereas the hinged rotor hub just requires the blades to lag or lead

Comment: I am thinking a bottom heavy design, so even in single rotor form I'd get some stability.. ?

Comment: Let me ask you too then; two rotor design, one on top on at the bottom, contra rotation, not coaxial. What wld be the easiest way to get basic navigation / stable hovering from this?

Comment: @NetSmoothMF I don't think stability is really the issue here. About two rotor designs, the easiest ways are also the most inelegant ways which is to mount them so the entire rotors can be tilted, or two mount both rotors in ducts with vanes that can direct the thrust. Have you considered a monocopter? Navigation is a problem on monocopters though. I'd personally prefer counter rotating propellers because you're sure to get double thrust and have the possibility of working it into a fixed wing format too for more efficiency when you need it.

Comment: The only design I would consider with two "coaxial" (coaxial isn't just when the motors share the same motor shaft. It's whenever they share the same axis of rotation including push-pullers)) propellers is the lag-lead hinged rotor hub design we are talking about since it is so compact and doesn't require additional servos. It has its hurdles though and I've yet to find a satisfactory way to make the hinged propeller hub. Machining is expensive and so are finding/making blades that would connect properly.

Comment: Yes monocopters seemed too hard to work with.. I like  counter rotating propellers as well; I do not know how to get navigation from them tho wout the souped-up rotors u and the article mentions. If you vary speeds on top-down rotors, what do you get? Have not tested this..

Comment: Looks like I have a lot of testing to do :) Thanks

Comment: Might be a language barrier here because I some things you just said don't really make sense. But if you vary normal coaxial props you just change the yaw on a rotor craft (or the roll on a fixed wing craft). Varying counter rotating props changes the rotation on two-axis (roll & yaw for fixed wing, yaw and either pitch or roll for rotorcraft). I've learned it's REALLY difficult to get something that performs better and is easier to build than the traditional designs without new enabling technologies. I would use the hinged rotorhub on a contra-rotating VTOL fixed wing